# SNAP extrusion (along normals)

Tags: extrude, snapping

[image]
I am trying to extrude A along normals and snap it to B (another mesh), but I am not able too.
Snap settings are vertex, active, affect scale

Comment: The problem is, snapping has options to affect _Move_, _Rotate_, _Scale_ (which you have enabled), but extruding along normals is none of these three. The best solution to get those two ridges the same size is to extrude them both a certain amount, which you can enter while extruding. The other not so exact method would be, extruding A while looking top down to adjust it so that it roughly matches B.

Comment: The second option is what I did, the first one is not possible since they are two different meshes and cannot be extruded at the same time.

Comment: Why is the first one not possible with two different meshes? I said to extrude both by a certain amount, a value which you can enter while extruding. Using a specific value makes it especially possible for different objects - if you have applied scale (which is always recommended when using beveling, extruding etc.) on both objects, you can extrude the first by let's say 0.1 m, then you go to the second object and extrude by 0.1 m as well. That's the good thing when using specific values and not just doing it randomly by eye.

Comment: By the way, apart from that I wrote extrude them "the same amount", not "at the same time", of course it is possible to extrude them both at the same time when they are different meshes. Select them both in _Object Mode_, switch to _Edit Mode_, select the faces you want to extrude and do it.

Comment: I have tried to select two items in OM and then switch to EM.
It is not possible to snap B to A anyway...

Comment: No, it's not possible to snap when you extrude - that's what I said in the beginning, but snapping is not what I was talking about in my first option...